# Using dotTrace with a 2005 web app

Tags: c#, profiling, dottrace

I am trying to run dotTrace 3.1 against a 2005 project using the ASP.NET Development Server option.

The settings I am using are:

```
ASP.NET Development Server - checked
Path to web-server root: c:\projects\fooProject
Virtual path on server: /barApplication
Port: 81 (automatically detected)
```

This will run, but no web page comes up, so I set:

```
Open start page in browser - checked
Page Url: http://localhost:81/barApplication/login.aspx
```

This throws a runtime exception saying:

> The parameter
>   'C:/Projects/fooProject\' is invalid.
>   Parameter name:
>   C:/Projects/fooProject\

I launched the webdev.webserver from the command line and everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?